# If INT equals 3,5,8,10,13,15 (etc)

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to have an if statement in PHP to calculate if an INT equals only certain numbers. The pattern would go like: 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 18, 20 etc. It adds 3, then 2, repeating. The pattern is consistent with the last digit (3,5,8,0), but I don't want to include the first 0.

I could do it this way, but it could go on forever...

```
if($int == 3 || $int == 5 || $int == 8 || $int == 10 ....)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This way also does multiples of 3...

```
if ($int % 3 == 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But doesn't do the pattern I want. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you simply check the last character to see if it's 3, 5, 8, or 0, and ignore it if the while thing is 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Get the remainder of the division by 10 and then check for 0, 3, 5 or 8.

```
if ($int > 0) {
  $int = $int % 10;
  if ($int == 0 || $int == 3 || $int == 5 || $int == 8)
  {
      //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Or even `if(in_array($int%10, array(0,3,5,8))) { … }`

Comment: The `if ($int > 0)` should come before the remainder calculation.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to only have one if statement. I created a new variable when checking for the remainder ($new_int = $int % 10) and added the old variable to the same if statement ($int > 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($t) {
    $mod = $t % 10;
    if ($mod == 0 || $mod == 3 || $mod == 5 || $mod == 8)
        echo $t;
}
$arr = array(3, 6, 8, 10, 20, 13, 15, 19);
array_map('check', $arr);
```